# Disable header side bar scroll

Tags: android, scroll, header, leanback

When a choose someone item in header side bar I get focus on the item and hidden search icon. How to do static header sidebar?

Answer (score 4):

Achieved by :

```
getHeadersFragment().getVerticalGridView().setWindowAlignment(WINDOW_ALIGN_HIGH_EDGE);
```

Comment: Do you use it in BrowseFragment? Try to put in onResume.

Comment: I was getting another issue, was not related with this, thanks for reply